# Ajax call is triggering twice

Tags: jquery

Below is my code.

```
function sendDataToServer(data) {
var hashids = new Hashids("this is my salt", 50);
//-----------------------------------------------------------
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Testing.aspx/SaveData",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'model': data }), 
    success: function (data) {
        var id = hashids.encode(data.d);
        PostResponse(id);
    },
    error: function (ex) {
        alert('Failed to Submit.');
    }
});
}

function PostResponse(id) {
if (id && id.d !== -1) {
    console.log(id);
    alert("Data Submitted Successfully!!!");
    var urll = "/Summary.aspx?Id=" + id;
    window.location.assign(urll);

}
else {
    alert('Failed to Submit.');
}
```

}

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaand how are you triggering this code, what errors do you have in the console?

Comment: please add code from where you are calling sendDataToServer()

Comment: on button click i am supplying parameters like this  sendDataToServer(data); No errors on console.

Comment: @Nikita, can you add that code please with button and javascript call

Comment: it might be possible that your click event is binded twice, because of which call is getting fired twice. So share your click event code.

Comment: @ Haresh below is my code
$(".validate").click(function () {
data.environment = {
        environmentType: environment,
        env_production: env_production
    };
 sendDataToServer(data);
});